# how to make def to get str(name of Dataframe or list) in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
def get_name(list):
  ??

li=[1]
get_name(li) # -> 'li' simple string, 'li'
f'{get_name(li)}' # -> 'li' not [1]
```

I think it is very simple question. but I can't solve.
Actually, value of list is not necessary.
desired input li (not 'li') , desired output 'li' (not li)

Comment: No.  Objects in Python do not know their own names, because they might have many names.  Perhaps what you want is a dictionary, where YOU control mapping names to objects.

Comment: @TimRoberts umm.. okay! I'm making another function, I need this logic in the middle of the original function. If so, I'll have to think of a different way. Thanks!!!

Comment: The need to know that is a red flag there is something wrong with your original function logic. Note that actually there may be objects never bound to a name, e.g. elements in a list created by comprehension.